# Unit test image file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, phpunit

I need to write a unit test for a file upload. I however can't figure out how I post the image using only php code.

Test function so far:

```php
public function testValidateAddAdminFormSuccess() {
    //prepare
    $testFile = array(
        'name' => 'test.jpeg',
        'tmp_name' => 'Macintosh HD/Applications/mampstack-7.1.30-0/apache2/htdocs/',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'size' => '6717',
        'error' => 0

    );
    $_FILES['image'] = $testFile;
    $_POST['productName'] = 'test';
    $_POST['price'] = 45;
    $_POST['productDesc'] = 'test description';
    $_POST['storeName'] = 'test store';
    $_POST['amount'] = 204;
    $_GET['product'] = 0;
    $database = new DatabaseTest();
    $adminModel = new AdminModel(NULL, $database);

    //run
    $adminModel->validateAddAdminForm();

    //validate
    $this->assertNotNull($adminModel);
    $this->assertTrue($adminModel->valid);
  }
```

My validate upload method in admin model:

```php
private function validateUploadFile() {

    $targetDir = 'images/';
    $this->imgUrl = $targetDir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($this->imgUrl, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['name']) || $this->isEditing() && !empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
      $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]['tmp_name']);
      if ($check !== false) {
      } else {
        $this->imageErr = 'File is not an image.';
      }
      if (file_exists($this->imgUrl)) {
        $this->imageErr  = "Sorry, file already exists.";
      }
      if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 2000000) {
        $this->imageErr = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
      }
      if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        $this->imageErr = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
      }
    } else if ($this->isEditing()) {
      $this->imageChanged = false;
    } else {
      $this->imageErr = 'Please upload an image.';
    }
    if (empty($this->imageErr)) {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $this->imgUrl);
      if ($this->isEditing() && !empty(basename($_FILES['image']['name']))) {
        $this->imageChanged = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

The file does not get recognized in my upload validation method. The method works perfectly though as I have tested it via the admin page it self. How do I upload the image without using a webpage?

The error it sets in imageErr: `Please upload an image'.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` has a check build in, for security reasons, to see if the file you want to move was actually uploaded to the server within the current request, it will fail if that is not the case. So you can not “fake” this, by simply populating $_FILES yourself. You need to perform an actual HTTP POST request.

Comment: (You probably get the “Please upload an image” message that comes even before move_uploaded_file here, due to the check if `$_POST['submit']` is set, which you did not supply in your made-up $_POST data. But even if you fixed that, what I said in the previous comment will still prevent it from working this way.)

Comment: @04FS Ok, that makes alot of sense. Just to be clear, there is no way to do a http post request in code? edit: do you maybe have a suggestion on how i could test this?

Comment: Check if any of the suggestions from here are any help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281614/how-to-test-file-upload-with-laravel-and-phpunit

Comment: @04FS I had already found that when searching google. Unfortunately not useful for my case. Appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a client HTTP for your test code.
Guzzle could help you with the [multipart](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart) option. It works great with PHPUnit.

Comment: I will look in to it.