# How to test upload file in laravel 5.0?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I want to test my file upload action .

I checked file type validation on that action . It is working from browser interaction , but I tried with phpunit it fail on validation .

I validate for accepting jpg or jpeg file only .

Here is my unit code

```
public function testWIthJpgImage()
{
    $_FILES = [
        'front_image' => [
            'name' => 'uitest',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'size'=> filesize(storage_path('data/uitest.jpg')),
            'error' => 0,
            'tmp_name' => storage_path('data/uitest.jpg')
        ]
    ];

    $response = $this->call('POST', '/api/test',[],[],$_FILES);
    $data = json_decode($response->getContent());
    dd($data); // here validation fail always
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

How can I test with file upload correctly on phpunit ? My laravel version 5.0 (old version) Laravel UploadFile is not available

Comment: enctype/multipart i think during the post call from test environment this is missing

Comment: How should I add that content type

Comment: i think you are using framework why don't you use the Log facade  and check what exists in Log?

Comment: No I think it is not a throw error ! It is something need to fix on phpunit file upload request (test pattern) because controller does it validation and return as usual ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281614/how-to-test-file-upload-with-laravel-and-phpunit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` Facade for this.

Here is an example of one of my projects where I upload & store a file. It also has a files table & model.

```
/** @test */
function create_new_file ()
{

    $payload = [
        'file' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg')
    ];

    // act
    $response = $this->post("/api/files", $payload);

    // test
    $response->assertStatus(201);

    Storage::disk('local')->assertExists(File::first()->path);
}
```

Don't forget

```
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

In addition you can use

```
Storage::fake('local');
```

in order to not persist the uploaded files (if you are using the Storage as I do). This is very handy so your tests don't create a bunch of files in your uploads folder.

Comment: I found it a lot ! But my laravel version is 5.0 very old ! UploadFile is not exist in Illuminate ...

Comment: oh sorry - you even said it below, I didn't see it

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is sovled but it is so weired to do that :) I set `$_FILES` and Symfony UploadedFile both :<

```
$_FILES = [
    'front_image' => [
        'name' => 'uitest',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'size'=> filesize(storage_path('data/uitest.jpg')),
        'error' => 0,
        'tmp_name' => storage_path('data/uitest.jpg'),
        'test' => true
    ]
];
$uploadedFile = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile(
  storage_path('data/uitest.jpg'),
  'uitest.jpg',
  'image/jpeg',
  filesize(storage_path('data/uitest.jpg')),
  0,
  true
);
$response = $this->call('POST', '/api/test',[],[],['front_image' => $uploadedFile]);
```