# How to create a fake Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile in a PHPUnit test?

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm unable to create a fake `UploadedFile` in my PHPUnit test.

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281614/how-to-test-file-upload-with-laravel-and-phpunit) for Laravel but I couldn't find one for Symfony.

This is my code:

```php
$path = '/tmp';
$originalName = 'MANA-BULL 12-2018 Ali.pdf';
$mimeType = "application/pdf";
$size = 4455;
$error = 0;
$fileRaw = new UploadedFile(
  $path,
  $originalName,
  $mimeType,
  $size,
  $error,
  $test = false
);

return $fileRaw;
```

I get the following exception:

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException: 
>   The file "/tmp" does not exist

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: So you're asking how to mock a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` object and disable the path-check in the (parent) constructor?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

In your tests directory, create a folder called fixtures. In that folder, place your test PDF file. From your test, you can now create an upload file like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Functional;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class UploadTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function test_uploadFile()
    {
        $uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(
            __DIR__.'../fixtures/foo.pdf',
            'foo.pdf'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$path has to be as following:
$path = '/tmp/MANA-BULL 12-2018 Ali.pdf';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).